# To reduce latency, I want to consume elasticsearch from the front end. Is it a good practice?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

To reduce latency, I want to consume elasticsearch from the front end. Is it a good practice to handle security, fault tolerance and rate limiting in frontend?

For a feature set that can be accessed across multiple device platforms (electron, browser and mobile), I want to consume elasticsearch from frontend directly to avoid network roundtrips and minimize latency. However I am concerned whether it is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT a good practice to access Elasticearch directly from your front-end code. The main reason why it is a bad idea is that you'll need to have the password or API key of the user making the queries inside your front-end code, so anyone can see it, and there's no way for you to protect it. Basic [security principles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/es-security-principles.html#security-protect-cluster-traffic) suggest that you need to keep your cluster shielded from public access. Performance and latency are not good reasons to bypass such recommendations.

Moreover, if people access your application from a browser, it's not clear how you want to implement rate-limiting inside the front-end code. Say your cluster can handle 1000 requests per second, and you have 2000 people using your application from browsers in distributed locations. How does the front-end code running in the browser of one user know about the 1999 other users doing queries at the same time?

Regarding fault tolerance, I'm not sure how you want to implement that directly in the front-end.

Comment: Glad it helped!